# Modify UIButton in specific cell in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've been struggling all day to find why my problem occurs.

I have a `UICollectionView` with cells that contain `UIButton`s and other `UIView`s.

My `UICollectionView` has 8 sections.

I want to modify the image of a `UIButton` in a specific cell when it is tapped.

I fire a method called "checked" to modify the image.

But instead of modifying only the image of the specific button, it modifies other buttons in other cells. When I press one of these other buttons, they all become "unchecked" again. So, they are linked but I really don't know why!

Here is my code :

```
- (ExCell*) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //create collection view cell
    ExCell *cell = (ExCell *)[collectView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ExCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // the index is the row number in section + the number of items in all previous sections
    int index = (int)indexPath.row;
    for(int k=0; k < indexPath.section ; k++){
        index += nbItemsInPart[k];
    }
    //configure cell :
    NSMutableString *text = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"Practical Exercise "];
    [text appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",index+1]];
    [text appendString:@"\n"];
    [text appendString:[titles objectAtIndex:index]];
    cell.label.text = text;
    [cell.reminder addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.done addTarget:self action:@selector(checked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.doIt addTarget:self action:@selector(doExercise:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.doIt setTag:index];
    [cell setTag:indexPath.section];

    // return the cell
    return cell;
}
```

Here is the method called when the button is tapped (it works but the result affects other additional buttons...) :

```
-(void)checked:(id)sender{
    if([sender imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] == [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"]){
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     }else{
         [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     }
}
```

This is the implementation of my custom cell :

```
@implementation ExCell
@synthesize imageView;
@synthesize label;
@synthesize reminder;
@synthesize done;
@synthesize doIt;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:aRect];
    {
        CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
        CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
        CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;

        done = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        done.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 85, 112);
        [done setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self addSubview:done];

        float widthLabel = 0.0f;
        UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
        if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)){
            widthLabel = (screenWidth-6)-158-156-3-85;
        }else if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)){
            widthLabel = (screenHeight-24)-158-156-3-85;
        }
        //we create the UIImageView in this overwritten init so that we always have it at hand.
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        imageView.opaque = YES;
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(86, 0, widthLabel, 112);
        [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        imageView.alpha = 0.7;
        imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        //set specs and special wants for the imageView here.
        [self addSubview:imageView]; //the only place we want to do this addSubview: is here!

        label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 0, widthLabel-5, 112)];
        [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        label.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        label.numberOfLines = 0;
        [self addSubview:label];

        widthLabel = widthLabel+85+2;

        doIt = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        doIt.frame = CGRectMake(widthLabel, 0, 156, 112);
        doIt.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
        [doIt setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"faireExo.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self addSubview:doIt];

        widthLabel = widthLabel+1+156;

        reminder = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        reminder.frame = CGRectMake(widthLabel, 0, 158, 112);
        reminder.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
        [reminder setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rappel.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self addSubview:reminder];

    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: When you say other buttons are affected, do you see these after you scroll, or do multiple check images appear in the same view with no scrolling? This is probably a consequence of cell reuse, if it's the former. Also, you shouldn't determine the equivalence of two images with "==", you should use isEqual: instead.

Comment: I see the other buttons after I scroll.

Comment: Well, then that's definitely a consequence of cell reuse. What behavior do you want? Do you only ever want one cell with the checked image (so if you click a different cell it checks that one and unchecks the one that was already checked)?

Comment: I replaced == by isEqual as you said. The problem still remains... I noticed the following : the UIButtons which change their image although they shouldn't are each in a separate section. I mean : when one button is tapped, one button per section is fired at the same time. I don't understand because what I do is to assign the method as target for each button individually and I modify the given button's image.

Comment: I would like to change only the button image ("checked" if it's "unchecked" and vice vers) for the cell whose button has been tapped (only for this precise row and section)

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. If you've already changed one button's image by tapping on it, what do want to happen if you tap on a button in another cell? Do you want the first button you tapped on to go back to the unchecked image or not? In other words, can there be multiple buttons with the checked image if the user taps on multiple cells, or only one at a time?

Comment: one at a time. When you tap a button, only this button can change. Here is a picture : http://jtschumi.com/uicollectionview.html

Comment: the button I want to respond to a tap is the one with the check sign (when it is unchecked it is just a circle). It means that an exercise has been done

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think we still have a misunderstanding. If you already have a button with the checked image (that exercise has been done), and the user now taps on a different exercise, don't you want that first exercise to still have the checked image? It's still done, right? That means (to my way of thinking) that you want to have multiple buttons with the checked image if they've completed more than one exercise. That's what I mean by more than one at a time (not that multiple buttons change with one tap).

Comment: yes you understood correctly. It thought you were thinking "that multiple buttons change with one tap" which is not what I want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of cell reuse you can't do it by setting the image in the button's action method. Instead, you should have a mutable array to keep track of the indexPaths of the cells you want to have checked images. You add (or delete) these paths from the array in the button's action method, but you actually set the image in cellForItemAtIndexPath based on what index paths are in the array. This example is for a table view, but the process is the same for a collection view.

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *checkedPaths; // I instantiate this in viewDidLoad

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    RDCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(customActionPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    if ([self.checkedPaths containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [cell.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else{
        [cell.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    return cell;
}



-(void)customActionPressed:(UIButton *) sender {
    id superView = sender.superview;
    while (superView && ![superView isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        superView = [superView superview];
    }// this while loop finds the cell that the button is a subview of


    NSIndexPath *selectedPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)superView];
    if ([self.checkedPaths containsObject:selectedPath]) {
        [self.checkedPaths removeObject:selectedPath];
    }else{
        [self.checkedPaths addObject:selectedPath];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[selectedPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]; // you would use reloadItemsAtIndexPaths: for a collection view
}
```

Comment: hi @rdelmar, do you happen to know how to get bubble tap events from a uibutton (embedded in a uicollectionviewcell) and let the uicollectionview handle the tap? question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335646/uigesturerecognizerdelegate-function-to-recognize-simultaneous-gestures-and-bubb

Answer (score 0):

That solved the problem! I had to call [collectionview reloadData] though :

```
-(void)checked:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSNumber *indice = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)button.tag];
    if ([self.checkedPaths containsObject:indice]){
        [self.checkedPaths removeObject:indice];
    }else{
        [self.checkedPaths addObject:indice];
    }
    [collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Thank you so much !!